# File Reader 1O Reading Text Fail

Tags: python, io

I am trying to read a movie script file ('sw_episode_iv.text') and count how many lines contain "THREEPIO" how can I improve my code below, it just prints zero

```
with open('sw_episode_iv.txt') as f:
    count = 0
    read_data = f.read()
    for line in read_data:
        if "THREEPIO" in line:
            count += 1
    print(count)
```

Comment: What is in the file being read that makes you think it shouldn't print 0?

Comment: Its the movie script of Star Wars, and looking at the file many many lines contain "THREEPIO"

Comment: Have you checked to see what is actually in `line`?

Comment: No, I haven't, to check do you suggest me putting print(line) in the for loop?

Comment: Unless you have a better idea; for example, using a debugger.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that line is actually just every character in the script, not whole lines, how do I remedy this?

Comment: Look up the other methods available to a file object.